# How to call parent's method in multilevel inheritance

Tags: c#, inheritance, unity-container

```
class A
{
  public Start(){}
}

class B:A
{
  public Start(){}
}

class C:B
{
 public Start()
{
   //i want to call B's Start()
  // when i do base.Start();
   //it calls A's Start();
}
}
```

How to call B's Start() from C's Start();
when i call base.Start() from C's Start() it calls A's Start();

Comment: use virtual/override; as it is now it is hiding, not inheritance

Comment: No - it calls `B.Start`.

Comment: If you don't have `base.Start()` in `B's Start()` method, than, as Konrad mentioned, it will call `B's Start()` not `A's Start()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sot sure what is you problem. Your methods are not virtual, hence according to 7.6.8. C# Language Specification:

> At binding-time, base-access expressions of the form `base.I` and `base[E]` are evaluated exactly as if they were written `((B)this).I` and `((B)this)[E]`, where `B` is the base class of the class or struct in which the construct occurs. Thus, `base.I` and `base[E]` correspond to `this.I` and `this[E]`, except this is viewed as an instance of the base class.

so those is in fact:

```
class C:B
{
   public Start()
   {          
      ((B)this).Start(); // same as base.Start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the hell users here give negative rating without specific any reason?

Comment: that is discouraging. :(